# If Array List Have Values Null

Tags: java, android

If you allow, I have two problems with the array list
I import values stored within a SharedPreferences and display them within a array list
But there are values coming from the SharedPreferences empty and displayed within the array and i do not want blank values to appear empty within the array as in the image
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wTR07.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lh95J.png)

I put this condition but it did not work I think it's wrong, can anyone put me the correct code to solve this problem

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate( savedInstanceState );
    setContentView( R.layout.activity_order );

    textView = (TextView) findViewById( R.id.quantityId );

    lv = (ListView) findViewById( R.id.list_view );
    sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences( "blanche",Context.MODE_PRIVATE );
    chickenBlanche = sharedPreferences.getString( "blancheS","" );

    SharedPreferences philadelph = getSharedPreferences( "philadelphia",Context.MODE_PRIVATE );
    philadelphiaCheese = philadelph.getString( "philadelphiaS","" );

    SharedPreferences mushroom = getSharedPreferences( "mushroom",Context.MODE_PRIVATE );
    mushroomS = mushroom.getString( "mushroomS","" );

    SharedPreferences superOf = getSharedPreferences( "super",Context.MODE_PRIVATE );
    superS = superOf.getString( "superS","" );

    SharedPreferences primo = getSharedPreferences( "primo",Context.MODE_PRIVATE );
    primoo = primo.getString( "primoS","" );

    SharedPreferences organo = getSharedPreferences( "oregano",Context.MODE_PRIVATE );
    oregano = organo.getString( "oreganoS","" );

    SharedPreferences pizzaMush = getSharedPreferences( "pizzaMushroom",Context.MODE_PRIVATE );
    pizzaMushS = pizzaMush.getString( "pizzaMushroomS","" );

    SharedPreferences cheesePizza = getSharedPreferences( "pizzaCheese",Context.MODE_PRIVATE );
    pizzaChesse = cheesePizza.getString( "pizzaCheeseS","" );

    SharedPreferences peproni = getSharedPreferences( "peproni",Context.MODE_PRIVATE );
    pepproni = peproni.getString( "peproniS","" );

    SharedPreferences forSeason = getSharedPreferences( "fourSeasons",Context.MODE_PRIVATE );
    fourSeasons = forSeason.getString( "fourSeasonsS","" );

    SharedPreferences italianPiz = getSharedPreferences( "italian",Context.MODE_PRIVATE );
    italianPi = italianPiz.getString( "italianS","" );

    SharedPreferences hotPiz = getSharedPreferences( "hotDog",Context.MODE_PRIVATE );
    hotDog = hotPiz.getString( "hotDogS","" );

    values = new ArrayList<String>();
    values.add( chickenBlanche );
    values.add( philadelphiaCheese );
    values.add( mushroomS );
    values.add( superS );
    values.add( primoo );
    values.add( oregano );
    values.add( pizzaMushS );
    values.add( pizzaChesse );
    values.add( pepproni );
    values.add( fourSeasons );
    values.add( italianPi );
    values.add( hotDog );
boolean retval = chickenBlanche.isEmpty();
    if (retval == true) {
        textView.setVisibility( View.GONE );
    } else {
        textView.setVisibility( View.VISIBLE );
    }
    boolean retval1 = philadelphiaCheese.isEmpty();
    if (retval1 == true) {
        textView.setVisibility( View.GONE );
    } else {
        textView.setVisibility( View.VISIBLE );
    }

    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>( this,R.layout.row_item,R.id.quantityId,values );
    lv.setAdapter( adapter );
```

In the Xml folder I want to put the listview inside the scroll view but the design also does not work as I want
I would like to put list view inside the scroll view with a host of other offers such as text View and the EditText
This is xml code

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:weightSum="1"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    tools:context="ka.noga.finalproject.Order"
    tools:showIn="@layout/app_bar_order">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/your_order"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/your_order"
    android:padding="15dp"
    android:textSize="25sp"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:textColor="@color/colorAccent"/>
<ListView
    android:id="@+id/list_view"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="0.6"
    android:layout_margin="15dp"
    android:dividerHeight="1dp"
    android:textSize="15sp" />

<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:ignore="UselessParent">
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/linear"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:weightSum="1">


    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/comment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="15dp"
        android:hint="@string/comment"
        android:textSize="15sp"
        android:textColor="#000000"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/comments"
        android:layout_weight="0.2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="15dp"
        android:text="@string/bill"
        android:textColor="@color/colorAccent"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:textSize="20sp" />

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/subtotal"
            android:textSize="15sp"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:paddingLeft="15dp"
            android:paddingRight="15dp"
            android:paddingBottom="8dp"
            android:id="@+id/subtotal"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/service_fee"
            android:paddingLeft="15dp"
            android:paddingRight="15dp"
            android:paddingBottom="8dp"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_below="@+id/subtotal"
            android:text="@string/service_fee"
            android:textSize="15sp"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/vat"
            android:paddingLeft="15dp"
            android:paddingRight="15dp"
            android:paddingBottom="8dp"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_below="@+id/service_fee"
            android:text="@string/vat"
            android:textSize="15sp"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/delivery_fee"
            android:paddingLeft="15dp"
            android:paddingRight="15dp"
            android:paddingBottom="8dp"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_below="@+id/vat"
            android:text="@string/delivery_fee"
            android:textSize="15sp"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/price"
            android:paddingRight="15dp"
            android:paddingLeft="15dp"
            android:paddingBottom="8dp"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:hint="@string/price"
            android:textSize="18sp"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" />
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/price_1"
            android:paddingRight="15dp"
            android:paddingLeft="15dp"
            android:paddingBottom="8dp"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_below="@+id/price"
            android:text="@string/price_1"
            android:textSize="18sp"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/price_2"
            android:paddingRight="15dp"
            android:paddingLeft="15dp"
            android:paddingBottom="8dp"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_below="@+id/price_1"
            android:text="@string/price_2"
            android:textSize="18sp"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" />
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/price_3"
            android:paddingRight="15dp"
            android:paddingLeft="15dp"
            android:paddingBottom="8dp"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_below="@+id/price_2"
            android:text="@string/price_3"
            android:textSize="18sp"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/total"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_below="@+id/delivery_fee"
            android:padding="15dp"
            android:text="@string/total"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:textSize="25sp" />
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/subtotal_price"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/subtotal_price"
            android:padding="15dp"
            android:textSize="25sp"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_below="@+id/price_3"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" />

    </RelativeLayout>
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/some_info"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        android:layout_weight="0.2"
        android:textColor="@color/colorAccent"
        android:padding="15dp"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:id="@+id/someInfo"/>
    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/name"
        android:layout_weight="0.2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="@string/your_name"
        android:layout_margin="15dp"
        android:inputType="textCapWords"/>

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/address"
        android:layout_weight="0.2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="@string/your_address"
        android:layout_margin="15dp"
        android:inputType="textCapWords"/>


    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/phone_number"
        android:layout_weight="0.2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="@string/phone_number"
        android:layout_margin="15dp"
        android:inputType="phone"
        />

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        >
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/send_order_by"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/send_order_by"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            android:padding="10dp"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:textAllCaps="true"
            android:textColor="@color/colorAccent"
            />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/email"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_below="@id/send_order_by"
            android:layout_margin="45dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="20dp"
            />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/whatsapp"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_below="@id/send_order_by"
            android:layout_margin="45dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="20dp"
            />
    </RelativeLayout>
</LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>
```

Comment: I would imagine that 80% of this code is not relevant to your problem.  Please create a [**Minimal**, Complete and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that demonstrates your issue.

Comment: Downvoted for lazy copying the WHOLE code instead of just the relevant part. http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 0):

```
    if (TextUtils.isEmpty(chickenBlanche)) {
        textView.setVisibility( View.GONE );
    } else {
        textView.setVisibility( View.VISIBLE );
    }


    if (TextUtils.isEmpty(philadelphiaCheese)) {
        textView.setVisibility( View.GONE );
    } else {
        textView.setVisibility( View.VISIBLE );
    }
```